# How can I run a python unittest where I need to tell the test where a file is?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am trying to write a Python `unittest` for a method that does some processing on a file. This is a large'ish binary file, so I don't want to recreate a temporary version of it in the `setUp()` method.

Is there a best practices for writing a `unittest` for a scenario like this?

- Would I pass in a file path as an argument?
- Would I download the file from a hosted service in `setUp`?
- Or is there a more accepted way to pass file paths into a unit test?

Comment: If the file is in the same repo/parentdir/etc as the test case and the code you're testing, there's nothing wrong with grabbing it using a relative file path in the test case.

Comment: It won't necessarily be in the same directory though. Or at least that is what I'm hoping to avoid.

Comment: The same directory as the test case? That's fine. Or do you mean it won't be in the same directory every time the test case runs?

Comment: Its not in the same directory as the test case. Nor will it be in the same directory every time. This is so co-workers can also run the `unittest` on their local environments as well.

Comment: You should coordinate with co-workers and have an agreed upon folder structure that the code is contained in.

Comment: Is that really best practices for this scenario? Or are `unittest`s just not typically suppose to handle files?

Comment: `unittest` can definitely test functions that operate on files. The typical practice is to have some kind of `test_files` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is to have a structured project along the lines of:

```
my_project
|--src
   |--foo.py
|--tests
   |--test.py
|--data
   |--file.dat
```

If you don't want to check the file into whatever source control you're using, simply add it to the ignore file.

This way, the location of the file never changes and you can reference it from both `foo.py` and `tests.py`

You shouldn't have to pass arbitrary file name arguments to run your test suite. If the file size is the issue, downloading it from a service every time seems no different than creating a temporary one.

Comment: Thanks for your input here. Since this appears to be a decent best practices approach, I'll architect my tests as such. Thanks!